# Absolute HTML elements and browser scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML div element with absolute position style enclosed by another div with "overflow:hidden" which is not without any position styles. When the browser scroll bar is scrolled down. The absolute styled div element stays in the same location. How to enclose it within the div element?
Please help me in this.
Thanks.

Comment: Post your code, follow the posting guidelines

Comment: You may need to change the position of the parent where you want to enclose it ... any different from static which is the initial value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent element the css attribute of `position:relative;`

Read this trick: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 1):

Put:

```
 position: relative;
```

On the parent css styles, this will then contain the child relative to this div and stay inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting outer div to position absolute and inner div to relative.